# The while loop I have in my program doesn't execute a few lines of code

Tags: python, while-loop, discord, discord.py

The while loop that I have in my discord.py bot program doesn't execute a few lines of code. I'm trying to make it so that the loop breaks everytime countdown (aka the number of messages sent to a user) equals the limit (aka the number of messages I want sent to the user), however I've noticed that the bot keeps sending messages even if the countdown reaches the limit. I am getting absolutely no error messages.

From what I know, the problem is in the code below. But I can't figure out where or what it is:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def spm_dm(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    countdown = 0
    await  ctx.send(":white_check_mark:")
    while True:
        await user.send(f'{content}')
        countdown = countdown+1
        if countdown == limit:
            await ctx.send("The loop has been broken, reason: timeout")
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: What is `limit`?

Comment: @Daweo It is a variable, it's the number of messages I want to send to a user (context: I'm trying to make a spam command, where my bot spams a user's dms with messages, so I want to be able to set a limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for loop as it will run the given limit times.

code for `for loop`:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def spm_dm(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    countdown = 0
    await  ctx.send(":white_check_mark:")
    for i in range(0,limit):
        await user.send(f'{content}')
    await ctx.send("The loop has been broken, reason: timeout")
```

and if you want to use same code with while loop then:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def spm_dm(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    countdown = 0
    await  ctx.send(":white_check_mark:")
    while countdown <= limit:
        await user.send(f'{content}')
        countdown = countdown+1
    await ctx.send("The loop has been broken, reason: timeout")
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Btw, is there no way to run the same code that I have with a while loop - I mean, is it necessary for me to use a for loop?

Comment: no problem and just mark this answer as accepted answer if works , and there are many ways to use it with while loop , so wait i will edit my answer with while loop